# LINQ to XML - Null

Tags: c#

I have an XML and trying to extract the Login and it didn't work. It always give me null.

```
<REQUEST xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LOGIN>
     <USERID>ID</USERID>
     <PASSWORD>12345</PASSWORD>
  </LOGIN>

   XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var login = from x in doc.Root.Elements("REQUEST").Elements("LOGIN")
                    select new login
                    {
                        UserId = x.Element("USERID").Value,
                        Password = x.Element("PASSWORD").Value
                    };
 var loginobject=login.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `doc.Root` it gets the root element of the XML doc, which in this case is `REQUEST`. You then don't want to get the `REQUEST` element, you want to get the `LOGIN` element because you're already at the `REQUEST` node.

Try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var login = from x in doc.Root.Elements("LOGIN")
            select new login
            {
                UserId = x.Element("USERID").Value,
                Password = x.Element("PASSWORD").Value
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is slightly malformed as you have `REQUEST` as the `Root` object. Try changing it to something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<REQUEST>
    <LOGIN>
        <USERID>ID</USERID>
        <PASSWORD>12345</PASSWORD>
    </LOGIN>
</REQUEST>
```

Or if you want to keep your XML the same, just take out the `Root.Elements("REQUEST")`:

```
var login = from x in doc.Root.Elements("LOGIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Root element is already **REQUEST**, so you want to jump directly to **LOGIN** child elements in your query.  I got the following working in **Linqpad** (great tool for testing/developing queries):

```
string xmlString = @"<REQUEST xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <LOGIN>
     <USERID>ID</USERID>
     <PASSWORD>12345</PASSWORD>
  </LOGIN></REQUEST>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
   var login = from x in doc.Root.Elements("LOGIN")
               select new 
               {
                   UserId = x.Element("USERID").Value,
                   Password = x.Element("PASSWORD").Value
               };
 var loginobject=login.FirstOrDefault();
 loginobject.Dump();
```